# Can NServiceBus publish to subscribers in the same AppDomain?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I have a simple web site. In my API controller I am capturing a Command and Sending it to a Handler. This works perfectly. In the handler I do some processing, and then Publish an event. The event NEVER gets published. I cannot even begin to describe the list of changes I have done to get this working, all to no avail.

About the only thing I can see that is different between my app and any sample is that mine has the publisher and subscriber in the same assembly. At this point in time I don't see the need for having a separate NServiceBus process, although I will likely do that at some point.

#### Handler

```
public sealed class PortfoliosHandler : IHandleMessages<CreatePortfolioCommand>, IHandleMessages<PortfolioCreatedEvent>
{
    public void Handle(CreatePortfolioCommand message)
    {
        // Processing logic, this executes just fine

        Bus.Publish(new PortfolioCreatedEvent { Name = portfolio.Name });
    }

    public void Handle(PortfolioCreatedEvent message)
    {
        // This NEVER executes
    }
}
```

#### Config

```
<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
        <add Assembly="Project.Domain" Namespace="Project.Domain.PM.Commands" Endpoint="messagebus" />
        <add Assembly="Project.Domain" Namespace="Project.Domain.PM.Events" Endpoint="messagebus" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

#### Config Code

```
NServiceBus.Configure.Transactions.Enable();

var config = NServiceBus.Configure.With();

config = config
    .AutofacBuilder(container)
    .Log4Net(new DebugAppender {Threshold = Level.Warn})
    .UseTransport<Msmq>()
    .PurgeOnStartup(true)
    .UnicastBus()
    .LoadMessageHandlers()
    .RunHandlersUnderIncomingPrincipal(false)
    .InMemorySubscriptionStorage()
    .UseInMemoryTimeoutPersister();

var bus = config
    .CreateBus()
    .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>()
                            .Install());
```

Not only does the event handler never fire, but no event message ever appears in the queues, and no record of it being published ever appears in the logs. It's almost as if I never sent it. Here are the log entries emitted by calling the Publish method above:

```
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:11,984 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.CorrelationIdMutatorForBackwardsCompatibilityWithV3
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:11,984 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.CorrelationIdMutatorForBackwardsCompatibilityWithV3
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:12,240 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Impersonation.Windows.WindowsIdentityEnricher
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:12,240 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Impersonation.Windows.WindowsIdentityEnricher
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:12,488 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Unicast.Monitoring.VersionMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:12,488 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Unicast.Monitoring.VersionMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:12,743 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Unicast.Monitoring.SentTimeMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:12,743 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Unicast.Monitoring.SentTimeMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:12,984 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Unicast.Monitoring.CausationMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:12,984 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Unicast.Monitoring.CausationMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:13,228 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Sagas.OriginatingSagaHeaderMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:13,228 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Sagas.OriginatingSagaHeaderMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:13,475 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Sagas.AutoCorrelateSagaOnReplyMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:13,475 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Sagas.AutoCorrelateSagaOnReplyMutator
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:13,721 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.MessageHeaders.MessageHeaderManager
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:13,721 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.MessageHeaders.MessageHeaderManager
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:13,969 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Gateway.HeaderManagement.GatewayHeaderManager
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:13,969 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Invoking transport message mutator: NServiceBus.Gateway.HeaderManagement.GatewayHeaderManager
```

These are the log entries that occur shortly thereafter:

```
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:58,866 DEBUG UnicastBus:0 - Finished handling message.
NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus: 15:52:58,866 [23] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - Finished handling message.
NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.TimeoutPersisterReceiver: 15:53:00,900 DEBUG TimeoutPersisterReceiver:0 - Polling for timeouts at 09/20/2013 15:53:00.
NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.TimeoutPersisterReceiver: 15:53:00,900 [17] DEBUG NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.TimeoutPersisterReceiver [(null)] <(null)> - Polling for timeouts at 09/20/2013 15:53:00.
NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.TimeoutPersisterReceiver: 15:53:01,152 DEBUG TimeoutPersisterReceiver:0 - Polling next retrieval is at 09/20/2013 15:54:01.
NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.TimeoutPersisterReceiver: 15:53:01,152 [17] DEBUG NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.TimeoutPersisterReceiver [(null)] <(null)> - Polling next retrieval is at 09/20/2013 15:54:01.
```

Please help. I am at my wits end. I ported from MassTransit to NServiceBus specifically because of the separation between Commands, Events, and Messages, but after 4 days of banging my head against this, MassTransit looking mighty good.

I'm sure it's something really stupid I'm doing, but I'm a noob to NServicebus. I even bought the book to try and help me, to no avail. I cannot see what I'm doing wrong, and I have tried so many permutations of settings I cannot keep track of them all.

### Updated 2013/09/23

A suggested I have:

- Split the handler in two: a PortfolioCreatedHandler and a CreatePortfolioHandler.
- Removed **sealed** from the handler
- Created my own SubscriptionStorage, wrapping InMemorySubscriptionStorage for debugging purposes

I was already using IEvent to mark my events, and ICommand for my commands. Commands are published by the web controllers, and only the handlers publish events.

My TestSubscriptionStorage class is being called for Init and GetSubscriberAddressesForMessage, and **not** for Subscribe and Ubsubscribe, so it looks like the problem is that the events are not being subscribed, which is difficult to reconcile with the logs entries below.

Here are the logs mentioning the PortfolioCreatedEvent:

```
NServiceBus.Unicast.Routing.StaticMessageRouter: 09:34:25,886 DEBUG StaticMessageRouter:0 - Routing for message: Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent set to messagebus@SL-T50009909L
NServiceBus.Unicast.Routing.StaticMessageRouter: 09:34:25,886 [1] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.Routing.StaticMessageRouter [(null)] <(null)> - Routing for message: Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent set to messagebus@SL-T50009909L
MessageType: Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent, Recoverable: True, TimeToBeReceived: Not set
MessageType: Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent, Recoverable: True, TimeToBeReceived: Not set
NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry: 09:34:25,906 DEBUG MessageHandlerRegistry:0 - Associated 'Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent' message with 'Project.PM.Handers.PortfolioCreatedHandler' handler
NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry: 09:34:25,906 [1] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry [(null)] <(null)> - Associated 'Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent' message with 'Project.PM.Handers.PortfolioCreatedHandler' handler
NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry: 09:34:25,916 DEBUG MessageHandlerRegistry:0 - Associated 'Project.Domain.PM.Commands.CreatePortfolioCommand' message with 'Project.PM.Handers.CreatePortfolioHandler' handler
NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry: 09:34:25,916 [1] DEBUG NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageHandlerRegistry [(null)] <(null)> - Associated 'Project.Domain.PM.Commands.CreatePortfolioCommand' message with 'Project.PM.Handers.CreatePortfolioHandler' handler
NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.XmlMessageSerializer: 09:34:26,120 DEBUG XmlMessageSerializer:0 - Initializing type: Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent, Project.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.XmlMessageSerializer: 09:34:26,120 [1] DEBUG NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.XmlMessageSerializer [(null)] <(null)> - Initializing type: Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent, Project.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptionManager: 09:34:35,445 INFO  MessageDrivenSubscriptionManager:0 - Subscribing to Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent, Project.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null at publisher queue messagebus@SL-T50009909L
NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptionManager: 09:34:35,445 [18] INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptionManager [(null)] <(null)> - Subscribing to Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent, Project.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null at publisher queue messagebus@SL-T50009909L
NServiceBus.AutomaticSubscriptions.DefaultAutoSubscriptionStrategy: 09:34:35,555 DEBUG DefaultAutoSubscriptionStrategy:0 - Autosubscribed to event Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent
NServiceBus.AutomaticSubscriptions.DefaultAutoSubscriptionStrategy: 09:34:35,555 [18] DEBUG NServiceBus.AutomaticSubscriptions.DefaultAutoSubscriptionStrategy [(null)] <(null)> - Autosubscribed to event Project.Domain.PM.Events.PortfolioCreatedEvent
```

Comment: If you do `Bus.Send...` does it then work? Following on from that do you really mean Publish or are you Sending?

Comment: Bus.Send works 100%. Bus.Publish does absolutely nothing. From what I understand Bus.Send should be used for Commands, and Bus.Publish should be used for Events.

Comment: At this point in time I have given up on NServiceBus. It just plain does not work at all. I have pulled the code from the NServiceBus Step by Step guide, and even that simple scenario doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks for buying the book! Yes, you can absolutely subscribe to events from the same AppDomain. Here are some thoughts as to what might be happening.

- Do you see log entries that indicate they are subscribing to the event? If not then they are not subscribing.
- You didn't post code for your command and event, so I'm not sure if you're using Unobtrusive Mode or directly implementing `IEvent`. NServiceBus 4 will not automatically subscribe to anything not recognized as an event.
- I see `InMemorySubscriptionStorage` in your code. This makes it a little difficult to actually look at that storage. You could try injecting an `ISubscriptionStorage` somewhere so that you can look at what's in there in the debugger. Or just switch to the default Raven subscription storage for awhile so that you can navigate to the RavenDB Studio at `http://localhost:8080` and look at the subscription documents.
- I'm not sure why you sealed your handler class. I can't think of a specific problem that might cause but it might be a good idea to take it out to eliminate it as a possible problem.
- Try separating your handlers into separate classes. There's no reason for one class to implement both anyway - the container will spin up new instances for each message so you can't share state, so it's probably best to not give another developer the impression that they could.
- Also [this issue](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/nservicebus/conversations/topics/20570) could have something to do with it?

And of course I get to be a broken record sometimes with this but I would [caution you not to publish events from a web application in the first place](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/why-not-publish-nservicebus-messages-from-a-web-application/).

Comment: It seems to subscribe okay, will update as above with more details. Will also give your ISubscriptionStorage approach a try.

Comment: The RavenDB Subscription won't work, as it requires full write permissions, and that requires a paid Raven license, and we're only in the evaluation phase. Will try the ISubscriptionStorage idea.

Comment: What? Your NServiceBus license provides full use of RavenDB for NServiceBus-related storage, like subscriptions.

Comment: Probably connected to the wrong RavenDB instance. Anyway, the point is moot. Nothing subscribes, despite the fact that the log seems to indicate it is.

Comment: Is there anything else you think I could try? At this point in time, I am considering giving up on NServiceBus and going back to MassTransit.  Either that or redoing my solution from scratch to not have the handlers in the same AppDomain as the web site.

Comment: Really difficult to say without a full repro. Possible to put the whole thing into a gist?

Comment: I swallowed my furstration and rebuilt the entire architecture from scratch last night, doing the bare minimum at each step in order to get the next step working. Once again, I can send messages, but cannot send events, they get published, but NServiceBus never subscribes to them. Can I email you the solution?

Comment: Okay. I got it working. What looks like was missing was an endpoint config to route from the Server component back to itself (as the Command handlers which raised the events and the Event handlers which processed them were hosted in the same solution).

Comment: I had the "aha" moment while reviewing a part of your book, so I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one. I used a lot of your techniques anyway to narrow down to the issue.

Comment: Good! I had assumed "messagebus" was the only endpoint name we were talking about. Glad you figured it out!